# How to return response object for bad request from Angular service to component

Tags: angular, express, angular-services

API returns below type of response -

```
export class ResponseObject{
statusCode: Number;
statusMessage: string;
response: string;
}
```

Service -

```
 singIn(user: User): Observable<ResponseObject>{
    return this._httpClient.post<ResponseObject>(`${this._svcURL}/users/signin`, user, this._httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));    
  }

  private handleError(errResponse: HttpErrorResponse){
    if(errResponse.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
      console.log("[Service] Client side error-",errResponse.error.message);
    }
    else{
      console.log("[Service]", errResponse);
    }
    return throwError("Oops! There is an issue with service. We're working on it.");
  }
```

Component -

```
loginUser(signinForm: any): void{
    let user: User = {
      email: signinForm.email,
      password: signinForm.password
    };
    console.log('[LOGIN-COMPONENT] User details ', user);

    this._moovApiService.singIn(user)
      .subscribe((response: ResponseObject) => this.responseObject = response,
      err => {
        console.log('[LOGIN-COMPONENT] ', err);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('[LOGIN-COMPONENT] Response from service ', this.responseObject);
      }
    );
  }
```

I am able to get values for ResponseObject type if the API returns success(200, 201), but if it is a bad request(404, 400) it doesn't return any values for ResponseObject. It ends up in handleError() method.

I want to get response for all status codes in my component and then process it. How I can do that?

Comment: why not move your error handling code in the subscribe function? like `err => this._moovApiService.handleError(err)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put `handleError()` as `public` and do

```
this._moovApiService.singIn(user).subscribe(
  (data) => this.response = data,
  (err) => {
    this._moovApiService.handleError(err)
    this.response = // put any value you want here
  },
  //() => complete
)
```

Comment: thanks! I have mapped my error response like this - this.response = err.error

Answer (score 0):

If you want all HTTP status codes to be treated as data and not as an error, you need to return a false Observable from your `handleError`. example:

```
private handleError(errResponse: HttpErrorResponse){
    return Observable.of(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch error before the subscription.

```
loginUser(signinForm: any): void {
        let user: User = {
            email: signinForm.email,
            password: signinForm.password
        };

        console.log('[LOGIN-COMPONENT] User details ', user);

        this._moovApiService.singIn(user).pipe(catchError(err => {
                console.log('[LOGIN-COMPONENT] ', err);
            }))
            .subscribe((response: ResponseObject) => {
                this.responseObject = response;
                console.log('[LOGIN-COMPONENT] Response from service ', this.responseObject);
            });
    }
```

Comment: `catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         let errorMessage = '';
         if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
           // client-side error
           errorMessage = 'Error: ${error.error.message}';
         } else {
           // server-side error
           errorMessage = 'Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}';
         }
         window.alert(errorMessage);
         return throwError(errorMessage);
       })`